# Erro Unexpected token for

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas em aplicar um `for` ao **fullcalender** para listagem de eventos num calendário. Ele da-me o seguinte erro:

> Unexpected token for

Aqui está o meu código:

```
for (i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
    {
        title: array5[i],
        start: array1[i]+'T'+array3[i],
        end:  array2[i]+'T'+array4[i]'
    },  
}
```

Eu já retirei o `for` para ver se o problema era dos `array` e deu certo, o que posso estar a fazer de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa colocar esse objeto em algum lugar:

```
{
    title: array5[i],
    start: array1[i]+'T'+array3[i],
    end:  array2[i]+'T'+array4[i]'
}
```

Por exemplo:

```
var objs = []

for (i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
    objs.push({
        title: array5[i],
        start: array1[i]+'T'+array3[i],
        end:  array2[i]+'T'+array4[i]'
    })
}
```

Comment: Boa resposta Jair +1

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 4):

O que o [@Jair](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70398/3635) disse está correto, apenas para complementar, você criou um objeto que não é adicionado a lugar algum e ainda adicionou uma virgula no final sem proposito, isto me faz pensar que você ainda precisa de algum conhecimento/domínio sobre o javascript.

Recomendo que leia:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos

Acredito que o uso seja este (leia os comentários no código):

```
var eventos = [];//Cria um array na variavel eventos

for (var i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
    //Adiciona o evento ao array
    eventos.push({
        title: array5[i],
        start: array1[i]+'T'+array3[i],
        end:  array2[i]+'T'+array4[i]'
    });
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: eventos //Adiciona os eventos ao fullCalendar
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda